# WPF ComboBox in Datagrid throws error if Binding is NULL

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid I want to edit. One column is a Combobox

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" >
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Company" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Companies}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company.Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is if the Company is `null` then I get the error

> Two-way binding requires Path or XPath

How can I get around that to allow the Company be set to null?

Comment: have you refreshed the itermsource? could you please share the code behind

Comment: Is the binding initially successful (I.e it's just the update that's incorrect)?

Comment: "Path=DataContext.Companies" Does the Companies property implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: There could be a few reasons for this, if you aren't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, if your updatesourcetrigger isn't correct, etc. Code behind would be helpful.

Comment: I think you only need to initialize "Companies" in the Model View constructor (ex: Companies = new List<string>()).

Answer (score 1):

`Text="{Binding Company.Name}"`always requires `Company`to be a valid object because the system wants to finally access the `Name` property. I still have some hope you can create a dummy Company object and set the Name to an empty string. Otherwise a converter helps:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, Mode=TwoWay}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Company" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Companies}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>


public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        Type myType = value.GetType ();
        PropertyInfo pinfo = myType.GetProperty ("Name");

        if (pinfo == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return (string)pinfo.GetValue(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The converter uses reflexion to access the `Name` property. If the type of `Company`is accessible for the converter (and the logic allows it) you can of course use is directly.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get any errors now. The only problem ist that when the column goes into edit mode and the combobox appears - the SelectedItem is NULL. But it should be the value from the TextBox in read-only mode.

Comment: I don't see a way to solve `SelectedItem` being Null. The reason is quite simple. There is a 1:1 relationship between the entries in the `Componies` list and the selected item. If an entry is Null and you select it the `SelectedItem` is for sure Null. And of course it is not possible to edit a property (in this case Name) of an object beeing Null. I again encourage you to add real, instanciated dummy objects instead of Null. It could be helpful to add an additional property to `Company` that indicates whether it is a dummy or a real company.

Answer (score 1):

The question already has a correct answer, so this is just a quick follow up.
Let's assume a demo ViewModel:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    CompanyType companyA = new CompanyType();
    companyA.Name = "Comp. A";
    CompanyType companyB = new CompanyType();
    companyB.Name = "Comp. B";
    Companies.Add(companyA);
    Companies.Add(companyB);
    PersonType person1 = new PersonType();
    person1.Id = 1;
    person1.Company = null;
    PersonType person2 = new PersonType();
    person2.Id = 2;
    person2.Company = companyB;
    persons.Add(person1);
    persons.Add(person2);
}
```

Now, what is not working in the ComboBox is that it is not changing the value of a Person's Company after a new value of a different Company is selected from the ComboBox: in the demo let's say we want assign both persons1 and 2 to companyA from the UI.

Furthermore CompanyB is **not** selected in the ComboBox of person2, if we don't bind the `SelectedItem` of the ComboBox to the Company property of the PersonType.

Here you find the fix to the Xaml of the Combobox

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        SelectedValuePath="Name"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Company}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Companies}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
```

The classes of my demo

```
public class PersonType // don't need to notify below
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CompanyType Company { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Please notice** also that, due to the binding of Combobox `SelectedItem`, person2 has its ComboBox item CompanyB **selected** in the beginning and now it is possible to change one's Company to CompanyA, for example.