# DataGrid ComboBox has no selected item when clicked the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

Recently I asked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919990/wpf-combobox-in-datagrid-throws-error-if-binding-is-null) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431811/wpf-combobox-dropdown-selection-fails), but could not fix the issue properly.

I have a DataGrid with ComboBox that can contain either a selected item or not. But if it does then the ComboBox should select it when the dropdown is opening which is doesn't.

[image: ComboBox]

Currently I have this code which works except when opening the dropdown the first time. It is nothing selected.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Company">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.Companies}" 
                       SelectedItem="{Binding Company, Converter={StaticResource NullValueConverter}}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company, Converter={StaticResource NullValueConverter}}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The `NullValueConverter` prevents exceptions if the Company is `null`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list?rq=1

Comment: What type is Company?  Is it an object, or primitive like String?

Comment: It is an object with properties `Id` and `Name` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your company was not a string as you mentioned in the comments then it can't display the Name unless you set
  `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` or create an ItemTemplate.
- You should use `SelectedItem="{Binding
  Company,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"` to update
  the value as soon as it changes because if you don't it will only
  raise ProperyChanged when you focus another cell or row.
- if your Property was immutable or a value type then you
  should use `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Company,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedValuePath="Content"`

.

Comment: Thanks. Tried your suggestions, but nothing changed. BTW It does display the name without `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` since I implemented `ToString()` in `Company`

Comment: @juergend then nothing is wrong with what you showed and you don't need the null converter, you mean if you open BMW the second row you see nothing selected?!

Comment: BTW I had to make sure the `SelectedItem` is one of the `ItemsSource` objects.

Comment: @juergend it has to be, but even if you set your SelectedItem to some instance that is not in your ItemsSource you'll get no exception, just no item will be selected